# paginate data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, cakephp, highcharts

I am working on javascript high charts..

now i want to paginate bars to avoid crowded display...

please anyone help me to paginate the data of  bars ..

i am working on cakephp 1.3..

below is my script to display data in highcharts bars..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    type: 'column'
    },
            title: {
            text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
            text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
            categories: [
           <?php  if($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Transport'){  ?>
            <?php foreach($content as $result) { ?>
            '<?php echo $result['origin_city']['origin_pcode']; ?> - <?php echo $result['dest_city']['dest_pcode']; ?>',
           <?php } ?> 
           <?php } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='CO2') { ?>
             <?php foreach($co2cont as $co2result) { ?>
      '<?php echo $co2result['origin_city']['origin_pcode']; ?> - <?php echo $co2result['dest_city']['dest_pcode']; ?>',
           <?php } } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Traveltime') { ?>
             <?php foreach($travel as $travelresult) { ?>
'<?php echo $travelresult['origin_city']['origin_pcode']; ?> - <?php echo $travelresult['dest_city']['dest_pcode']; ?>',
           <?php } } ?>           

                  ],
                                crosshair: true

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                                title: {
                                text: null
                                }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} mm</b></td></tr>',
                                footerFormat: '</table>',
                                shared: true,
                                useHTML: true
                        },
                        legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                                align: 'center',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                floating: true,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                                dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                        format: '{point.y}'
                                }
                        }
                        },
                        labels:
                {
                enabled: false
                },
                        series: [{
                        name: '<?php  if($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Transport'){  ?>
    <?php echo $result['u_data']['Mode']; } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='CO2') { ?>
    <?php echo $co2result['u_data']['Mode']; } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Traveltime') { ?>
    <?php echo $travelresult['u_data']['Mode']; } ?> Cost',
                                data: [
             <?php  if($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Transport'){  ?>
            <?php foreach($content as $result) { ?>
            <?php echo $result['u_data']['TotalCost']; ?>, <?php } ?> 

           <?php } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='CO2') { ?>
            <?php foreach($co2cont as $co2result) { ?>
           <?php echo $co2result['u_data']['totalco2_emmission']; ?>,
            <?php } } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Traveltime') { ?>
            <?php foreach($travel as $travelresult) { ?>
           <?php echo $travelresult['u_data']['Days']; ?>,
            <?php } } ?>

               ]

                        }, {
                        name: 'Road cost',                        

                                data: [<?php  if($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Transport'){  ?>
            <?php foreach($modecost as $charge) { ?>
            <?php echo $charge['u_data']['totalcharge']; ?>, <?php } ?>         
           <?php } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='CO2') { ?>
             <?php foreach($co2modecost as $co2mode) { ?>
             <?php echo $co2mode['u_data']['CO2totalcharge']; ?>,
            <?php } } elseif ($this->Session->read("SAVING_TYPE")=='Traveltime') { ?>
             <?php foreach($travelmodecost as $travelmoderesult) { ?>
             <?php echo $travelmoderesult['u_data']['traveldays']; ?>,
            <?php } } ?>
            ]
                   }]
                });
                });
</script>




 <div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? If your PHP is working fine, then you could just use exemplary data and JS - no PHP. By paginating your data you mean vertical panning? There is [a plugin for this](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/27/Y-Axis%20Panning). Or do you mean some kind of button-controlled data swapping? Then you could change series data using [series.setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData)

Comment: yes my php code is working fine sir...and i cannot use any javascript in my page....i am using cake pagination...but i dont no what the problem...the pagination is not echoing numbers...in my view file.

Comment: "cannot use any javascript in my page" - but Highcharts chart is build using JavaScript... From what you have described it seems that PHP is not echoing expected data. You could start with eliminating Highcharts from equation and just trying to get proper data - then it can be displayed in console using `console.log()` in JS. After you will fix your problems with PHP, then chart should be build with correct data without any problems. Or did I misunderstood something?